# NodeJS+Express:As I use links to navigate I cannot load the CSSs

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I am very novice at Node.

I made the server run as follows (index.js):

```
var express = require('express'),
    views   = require('./routes/views');
var app = express();

// Get an instance of router
//var router = express.Router();
//app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/routes/keenIO/assets/css'));
app.use('/', views);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

I use the router in this way, setting also the, I guess correct ones, paths to the static content (views.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var path    = require("path");
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname+'/keenIO/assets'));
router.use('/specificAssets', express.static(__dirname+'/keenIO/examples'));
//app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/routes/keenIO/assets/css'));

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //res.send('GET handler for /views route.');

    var indexPatch = path.join(__dirname+'/keenIO/examples/connected-devices/index.html');
    res.sendFile(indexPatch);
    //res.send(__dirname);
});

router.get('/rules', function(req, res) {
    //res.send('GET handler for /views route.');

    var indexPatch = path.join(__dirname+'/keenIO/examples/connected-devices/rules.html');
    res.sendFile(indexPatch);
    //res.send(__dirname);
});

router.get('/json', function(req, res) {
    //res.send('POST handler for /views route.');
  var fs = require('fs');
  //res.send('HOLA MUNDO');
  var obj;
  fs.readFile('network-big.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
     res.send(obj);
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

So, In the .html file I use for example this to reach to the css, and similar to reach to the javascript files:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/keen-dashboards.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="specificAssets/connected-devices/connected-devices.css" />
```

I start this and everything is fine, but as I try to load the same index.html for example clicking on a link ( with the path to it: specificAssets/connected-devices/index.html) it has no style at all.

EDITED 25/10/16 3:30 p.m:
Well, inspecting the element with Chrome, as I click on the links I get doubled one part of the patch, getting for some static resources http://localhost:3000/assets/assets/resource.{css/js}
But it appropriately loaded the first time I access to the .html with http://localhost:3000. I am confused...

Any advise will be very appreciated.

Best regards,

Iván

Answer (score 1):

Create a proper structure and keep all your html files in a views folder and do it following way that will work for you And for styling just keep your css in html file only or keep them in same folder and require file in html **Easiest way to do is to keep your html and style in same file**

```
router.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


 router.get('/', function(req, res) {

       res.render('index');
    });
```

If you want to use a proper structure then you need to know this thing as well

Since .css files are static files you have to serve them to the clients. However, you do not serve static files as a express middleware. Add the following middleware to your express app and move the css folder under the public directory (you should create a public directory)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: Hello Shumi. One question related to your answer. I cannot use .render as I get an error always I use it, it reports me I don't have the http module, so I use sendFile instead. I guess it won't be related to my issue but...

Comment: Besides I have the router.use in order to reach to the content. Is not it a good way of doing this?

Comment: @Fulgor3 render is basically used for another tempting engines(ex. JADE) to convert them into html and display. if you are using html only you can simply use sendFile() as well . Just keep your css in same folder where you kept your html file and use path.join to see your html with style
we use app.use if we want to add some middleware

Comment: So there is not a way of organizing everything in different folders, @Shumi Gupta??? Because I think it is very messy to have all the resources in the same folder. Besides I don't understand yet why it loaded firstly and lose the css after clicking on a link.

Comment: I did the app.use in the router concretely router.use serving the static files in views.js file. I keep trying to get it well but it still doesn't work.